# Database implemenation for Grouped Tagging

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, tags, tagging

I need to implement a tagging system which is something like this :-

Every user can be tagged on the basis of his education. ( Tags be : Primary, secondary, High School) and these Tags fall under the umbrella of "education".Similarly the user may also be tagged on his interest(Cricket, Football, Rock music, pop music...) Cricket and football come under "Sports", rock music and pop music come under "Music".

Current design is :

```
User Userid    TagID TagName        UserId TagID  
===========    =============        ============
1    User1      1    Pop              1     1   
2    user2      2    Rock             1     2
                3    Techno           1     5
                4    Cricket          1     6
                5    Football         2     1
                6    Primary Scl.     2     4
                7    Secondary scl    2     7
```

These 3 form the major tables that allow many to many relationship between users and tags.

secondary tables are:

```
(Music)                        (Sports)                 (Education)
TagID MusicID MusicType        TagID SportID  Sport     TagID EducationID Education
=======================        ====================     ============================
 1    1       Pop Music        4        1     Cricket    6        1        Primary
 2    2       Rock Music       5        2     Football   7        2        Secondary
 3    3       Techno Music
```

the problem in this structure is that a TagID from table TagTable can be referenced by both Music and Sports if care is not taken.There is a chance that pop music and cricket will refer to the same TagID if the developer doesn't take necessary care.

How do I avoid this possibility of multiple referencing ?

Note : The secondary tables have been used to check if the tags fall under the same umbrella. This is feature of grouping tags is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

*NOTE: Tag names are globally unique in the model above. If you need to make them unique per category, just include TAG_CATEGORY_ID in the UNIQUE constraint TAG.U1.*

---

BTW, do you need to limit user to only one tag from certain categories? For example, can user have both Primary and Secondary tags from the Education category, or not? If you need to limit this, you'll need to reference such tags in a different way (as opposed to the "simple" junction table USER_TAG) and there will be certain complications to prevent mixing "single" and "multi" tags...

Comment: A few tags need to have limits. Like a user can have either primary or secondary, Other tags like Sports or music can be "multi". I understand there will be complications and would be great if you could help with that.